# IF Else count(*) in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have `view` named as `view_date_time_records`

[image]

What I'm trying to do here is `count(*)` the records whether the `hours`

is greater than `8 hours` or below `6 hours`

If `1 row` is greater than or equal to (>=) `8 hours` this should be counted as `1`

and

If I have `1 row` that is less than or equal to (<=) `6 hours` this should be counted as `0.5`

Ex:

I have `3 rows` with `hours` value of `10,10,5`

that means, the output is: **2.5**

I just want to do this on my query not on my php codes.

I only have simple query like this

`SELECT count(ACNo) FROM view_date_time_records WHERE hours >= 8`

Still trying to explore the conditional for this kind of query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use conditional summation here:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN hours >= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS greater_than_8,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hours <= 6 THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS less_than_6
FROM view_date_time_records;
```

The above query would give a table-level report.  If instead, for example, you wanted to report these per account, you could try:

```
SELECT
    ACNo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hours >= 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS greater_than_8,
    SUM(CASE WHEN hours <= 6 THEN 0.5 ELSE 0 END) AS less_than_6
FROM view_date_time_records
GROUP BY
    ACNo;
```

**Edit:**

Per the suggestion of @Akina, we can try the below more concise form:

```
SELECT
    SUM(hours >= 8) AS greater_than_8,
    SUM(hours <= 6) / 2 AS less_than_6
FROM view_date_time_records;
```

Comment: In MySQL you do not need to use CASE, `SUM(hours >= 8)` is enough.

Comment: @Akina Yes, that would work for the first sum, but the second case wants to count 0.5.  I guess we can divide by two though.

Comment: Yes. Divide by 2 one time for a group is faster :) than use additional CASE for each separate value.